# WPF FrameworkElementFactory Image creation Not able to AddHandler for MouseDownEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls, frameworkelementfactory

I am using Framework ElementFactory for creating a image in DataTemplate. While trying to handle the MouseDown Event for the Image type, an exception is thrown - "Handler Type is not valid.

How can we add an MouseDownEventHandler for the FrameworkElementFactory of type Image

```
FrameworkElementFactory imageSecondaryContent = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Image));
imageSecondaryContent.SetValue(Image.WidthProperty, imgWidth);
imageSecondaryContent.SetValue(Image.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);
imageSecondaryContent.Name = imageName;
Binding tmpBindingSecondaryContent = new Binding();
tmpBindingSecondaryContent.Source = IconLibary.GetUri(IconStore.ExclaminationPoint);
imageSecondaryContent.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, tmpBindingSecondaryContent);
imageSecondaryContent.AddHandler(Image.MouseDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Test));
```

The last line throws an exception. Please help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer. It is

```
imageSecondaryContent.AddHandler(Image.MouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Test));
```

Please close the question if you think it needs to be closed.

Comment: It is not only OK, you should. If an answer has been answered correctly that answer should be accepted.